# Will you tell me what she told you?

Tags: present-perfect

> - She will answer my question tomorrow.
> - Will you tell me what she **told** you (tomorrow)?

> - She will answer my question tomorrow.
> - Will you tell me what she **has told** you (tomorrow)?

I think that the past simple is OK, is the present perfect possible?

Comment: It could even be simple present: "*Let me know what she **says**.*".

Comment: But you version is missing the future simple. It mustn't be simpler.